# PHP - Fetching xml values and returning conditional values

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xmlreader

I'm fetching some xml and convert it to csv similar to this post [PHP - Fetch correct XML values if elements have similar tags per record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797403/php-fetch-correct-xml-values-if-elements-have-similar-tags-per-record). If I have an incorrect Date element like '0000-00-00' ... in the csv I want it to be empty ''.

This is my structure

XML Elements:

```
<abc:ABC>5EXZX4LPK</abc:ABC>
<abc:Date>0000-00-00</abc:Date> 
<abc:Name>I Bornheim</abc:Name>
```

php xpath xmlreader:

```
fputcsv(
  $output, 
  [
    $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:ABC)', $node),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:Entity/abc:Date)', $node)        
    $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:Entity/abc:Name)', $node)
  ]
);
```

Output:

```
5EXZX4LPK,0000-00-00,"I Bornheim"
```

Desired Output:

```
5EXZX4LPK,,"I Bornheim"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it's a valid date by decomposing it into the year-month-day and then using [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)...

```
$date = $xpath->evaluate('string(abc:Entity/abc:Date)', $node);
$parts = explode("-", $date);
$date = (count($parts)== 3) &&
    checkdate($parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[0]) ? $date : '';
```

This explodes the date with `-` and checks there are 3 parts and that all the parts make up a valid date.